# What does calling addEventLister twice do?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```
elemen.addEventListener('click',func,false);
elemen.addEventListener('click',func,false);
```

When `elemen` is clicked, will the function `func` be called twice, or just once?

If it is called twice, then is there a solution to check if the same event listener already exists on `elemen`?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

In your example, `func` will **not** be called twice on click, no; but keep reading for details and a "gotcha."

From [`addEventListener`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener) in the spec:

> If multiple identical `EventListeners` are registered on the same `EventTarget` with the same parameters the duplicate instances are discarded. They **do not** cause the `EventListener` to be called twice and since they are discarded they do not need to be removed with the `removeEventListener` method.

*(My emphasis)*

Here's an example:

```js
const target = document.getElementById("target");

target.addEventListener("click", foo, false);
target.addEventListener("click", foo, false);

function foo() {
    const  p = document.createElement("p");
    p.textContent = "This only appears once per click, but we registered the handler twice.";
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="target" value="Click Me">
```

It's important to note, though, that it has to be the **same function**, not just a function that does the same thing. That's because it works by looking for the function on the element's handler list, and two distinct functions — even if equivalent — aren't the same:

```js
const f1 = () => {};
const f2 = () => {};
console.log(f1 === f2); // false
```

For example, here I'm hooking up four separate functions to the element, all of which will get called:

```js
const target = document.getElementById("target");

for (let count = 0; count < 4; ++count) {
    target.addEventListener("click", () => {
        const p = document.createElement("p");
        p.textContent = "This gets repeated.";
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }, false);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="target" value="Click Me">
```

That's because on every loop iteration, a *different* function is created (even though the code is the same).

Comment: I am not the OP but this answer helped me a lot too. Thank you !!

Comment: I think the first code snippet needs the `<input type="button" id="target" value="Click Me">` fragment.  Otherwise it gives the error: _Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null_

Comment: @Wyck: **Thanks!!** Indeed, two years ago when I edited the answer to provide Stack Snippets, I appear to have forgotten *rather* an important part of that first one. :-)

Comment: Great answer! I wish more posters would answer questions here on Stack Overflow as clearly and thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

I would just like to add to the great answer provided by @T.J. Crowler.

I had a specific task, that required me to add a same callback twice for the same event to an HTML element. It is true, that the second one discards the first, but:

> If multiple identical EventListeners are registered on the same
>   EventTarget with the same parameters, the duplicate instances are
>   discarded. They do not cause the EventListener to be called twice, and
>   they do not need to be removed manually with the removeEventListener()
>   method.
>
> Note, however that when using an anonymous function as the handler,
>   such listeners will NOT be identical, because anonymous functions are
>   not identical even if defined using the SAME unchanging source-code
>   simply called repeatedly, even if in a loop.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners (as of 5th of February 2020.)

So if the second EventListener has its handler as an anonymous function it would not discard the first. So it would simply be called twice.

An alternative for your loop solution.

Comment: I believe @T.J. Crowder's answer already uses anonymous functions as an example, they are just created in the loop

Comment: @Learning2Code Thank you! I haven't noticed that. I just came back to share what helped me, since the loop solution didn't work for me. But I'm pretty sure I just implemented it the wrong anyway.