# addEventListener: Event doesn't get added in certain placement (keydown)

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I added 2 Event Listeners in my document, although one of them does not work when placed after the other, but works fine when placed before the other, I couldn't manage to know why?
Specified code:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  alert("key was pressed!");
});
```

When it is placed above the "click" event listener, it works fine, problem is when it is place after it, only the "click" works but not the "keydown".

My code:

```
var buttonLength = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

document.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  alert("key was pressed!");
});  //Works here

for (i = 0; i <= buttonLength; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    switch (buttonInnerHTML) {
      case "w":
        var tom1 = new Audio('sounds/tom-1.mp3');
        tom1.play();
        break;

      case "a":
        var tom2 = new Audio('sounds/tom-2.mp3');
        tom2.play();
        break;

      case "s":
        var tom3 = new Audio('sounds/tom-3.mp3');
        tom3.play();
        break;

      case "d":
        var tom4 = new Audio('sounds/tom-4.mp3');
        tom4.play();
        break;

      case "j":
        var snare = new Audio('sounds/snare.mp3');
        snare.play();
        break;

      case "k":
        var crash = new Audio('sounds/crash.mp3');
        crash.play();
        break;

      case "l":
        var kick = new Audio('sounds/kick-bass.mp3');
        kick.play();
        break;
      default:
        console.log(buttonInnerHTML);

    }
  });

}
document.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  alert("key was pressed!");
}); //Doesn't work here
```

Comment: You are making same events. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364298/will-the-same-addeventlistener-work)

Comment: It doesn't work because there will be a `TypeError` in the console. Arrays are zero-based, hence the last element is at index `Array.length - 1` but your loop also tries to access an element at index `Array.length`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in for loop.
Too many iterations, change to:

```
for (i = 0; i < buttonLength; i++) //(remove equal sign)
```

Your code is throwing error so engine can't continue to next keypress event