# Getting multiple a sound and countdown timer to work using the same button

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to implement sound into my program that whenever you click the start button, it starts both the sound and the count down at the same time, but currently, it only starts the time. I've gotten it to work by itself without the timer but every time I try to connect it using `addEventListener` it just doesn't seem to connect to the sound. Does anyone see anything I'm missing or am I using it wrong?

This is my HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="cssstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="loopv3.js"></script>
    <link href="Password.html" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <audio id="sound" ; src="us-lab-background.mp3"></audio>
    <div id="under" style="position: absolute">
      <img
        src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/M7fDTpDnJcZ4dt3myngzxi.jpg"
        alt="space background"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      />
    </div>
    <div id="countdowntimer" style="left: 44%; top: 105%; position: absolute">
      <p id="countDown" ; style="color: white">Seconds till Blast Off!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="top" style="left: 41%; top: 60%; position: absolute">
      <img
        src="https://images-platform.99static.com/VMvW_L-joavx2q3oj5fSTZOiGwI=/0x0:1000x1000/500x500/top/smart/99designs-contests-attachments/114/114579/attachment_114579370"
        alt="UAT Space Logo"
        width="45%"
        height="50%"
      />
    </div>

    <div id="countdowntimer" style="left: 43.5%; top: 110%; position: absolute">
      <p id="timer"></p>
      <button onclick="countDown()">Start Countdown!</button>
    </div>

    <div id="text" style="left: 20%; top: 97%; position: absolute">
      <b style="color: white">Rocket Launch Timer.</b>
    </div>

    <button id="stopTime" onclick="stopCount()">Stop!</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is my JavaScript

```js
var timedown;
var x = document.getElementById('sound');
x.addEventListener('click', countDown);
x.addEventListener('click', noise);
function countDown() {
  var currTime = 55;
  timedown = setInterval(function () {
    currTime = currTime - 1;
    document.getElementById('countdowntimer').innerHTML =
      'The time is:' + currTime;
    if (currTime == 0) {
      clearInterval(timedown);
      document.getElementById('countdowntimer').innerHTML = 'BLASTOFF!';
    } else if (currTime <= 25) {
      document.getElementById('countdowntimer').innerHTML =
        'Half way to launch ' + currTime;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function stopCount() {
  clearInterval(timedown);
}
function noise() {
  var sound = document.getElementById('countdowntimer');
  sound.play();
}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `</div>` tag in your HTML

Comment: `<audio id="sound";` - there should not be the `semi-colon` in there

Answer (score 1):

First issue - in your function `noise()`, you have it getting the element `"countdowntimer"`. Remove this all together, and replace `sound.play();` with `x.play();` as you already define `var x = document.getElementById("sound");`

Next, create a new function to call both `countDown()` and `noise()`

I've replaced the audio in this snippet so I could test it.

```js
var timedown
var x = document.getElementById("sound");
x.addEventListener("click", countDown);
x.addEventListener("click", noise);
var currTime = 55

function activate() {
  countDown();
  noise();
}

function countDown() {
  timedown = setInterval(function() {
    currTime = currTime - 1;
    document.getElementById("countdowntimer").innerHTML = "The time is:" + currTime;
    if (currTime == 0) {
      clearInterval(timedown);
      document.getElementById("countdowntimer").innerHTML = "BLASTOFF!"
    } else if (currTime <= 25) {
      document.getElementById("countdowntimer").innerHTML = "Half way to launch " + currTime;

    }
  }, 1000);
};

function stopCount() {
  clearInterval(timedown)
  x.pause();
};

function noise() {
  x.play();
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="cssstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="loopv3.js"></script>
  <link href="Password.html">
</head>

<body>
  <audio id="sound" ; src="https://sounds-mp3.com/mp3/0011247.mp3"></audio>
  <div id="under" style="position: absolute">
    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/M7fDTpDnJcZ4dt3myngzxi.jpg" alt="space background" width="100%" height="100%"> </div>
  <div id="countdowntimer" style="left:44%; top: 105%; position: absolute">
    <p id="countDown" ; style="color:white"> Seconds till Blast Off!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="top" style="left: 41%; top: 60%; position: absolute">
    <img src="https://images-platform.99static.com/VMvW_L-joavx2q3oj5fSTZOiGwI=/0x0:1000x1000/500x500/top/smart/99designs-contests-attachments/114/114579/attachment_114579370" alt="UAT Space Logo" width="45%" height="50%"> </div>

  <div id="countdowntimer" style="left: 43.5%; top: 110%; position: absolute">
    <p id="timer"></p>
    <button onclick='activate()'>Start Countdown!</button>






    <div id="text" style="left: 20%; top: 97%; position: absolute">
      <b style="color:white">Rocket Launch Timer.</b>
    </div>


    <button id="stopTime" onclick='stopCount()'>Stop!</button>

</body>








</html>
```

Comment: I could not edit your answer. It says suggested edit queue is full. so if you could edit your answer to add x.pause(); in stopCount function would be awesome so that the sound pauses when the user clicks stop

Comment: That's done - although you'll still need to change the sound file out yourself again. I would also suggest changing the text colour for ```countdowntimer``` as black-on-black isn't legible.

Comment: Im not the one who asked the question :D you are saying that to a wrong user. thanks for the edit though

Comment: Ahh, my bad. Yeah, I did notice that it didn't stop the audio but decided to just fix the problem then fix the code entirely :D

Comment: thank you, guys! and I know I have my countdown timer set to white on a CSS file. it wasn't working in my html so I just did a css link it and turned it to white lettering

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add two eventlisteners on the same element with the same event. The previous one will be discarded. Instead create a new function which will call the other two functions on event. Eg

```
x.addEventListener("click", ()=>{ countDown(); noise();});
```

More Information about this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364298/will-the-same-addeventlistener-work)